# On comparable hardware, is Mathematica known to perform better in one operating system over the others?

Tags: compile, windows, mac-os-x, linux

Have any benchmarks been published by Wolfram Research to compare the performance of Mathematica in the major operating systems (Windows 10, Linux, MacOS)?  If not, has anyone here performed such tests?

Along with general performance, it would be extremely helpful to read information regarding the difference in performance of `Compile`d code in the various operating systems.

Comment: Dunno about the kernel, but the FE often works much, much better on Mac than Windows (or Linux, I think).

Comment: @b3m2a1 At least Szabolcs and I cannot confirm this. The Mathematica front end is best served with an ugly tasting Microsoft Windows. I'm pretty OK with how it runs on Linux and in some cases, it does a better job there than on OSX.

Comment: @halirutan interesting. My experience (admittedly from v10, the last time I used Windows with M-) was that run-of-the-mill `Dynamic` stuff would work fine on my old, old Mac and destroy my reasonably-new Windows work computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica comes with a `` <<Benchmarking` `` package that let's you perform a benchmark of your computer. In the resulting report, you find how you compare to different other computers and operating systems:

```
<< Benchmarking`
BenchmarkReport[]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The list of the tested system is additionally given in the variable `$BenchmarkSystems` after you loaded the package.

The performance of `Compile` itself depends on your C-Compiler if you compile to C. Although I'm sure that some of the tests contain code that uses auto-compilation, an explicit comparison for compiled code is not given.

Comment: This is very helpful!  Thank you very much.